# MySQL select unreaded messages

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

So i'm trying to select unread messages with a query, but the results are blank. I need to get the info from a seperate table read so it will know it was read or not. Im trying to do something like a IF statement so if readed not exists it will be unread, but i can't get it fixed

this is my query:

```
 SELECT * FROM notify 
 INNER JOIN readed ON readed.acc_ID = '26' AND readed.user_ID = '6' 
        AND readed.msg_ID = notify.ID AND readed.readed != '1' OR readed.ID IS NULL 
 WHERE notify.groep = '1'


DB - readed

ID         - int
user_ID    - int
acc_ID     - int
msg_ID     - int
readed     - enum ('0','1')

DB - notify

ID         - int
notfi      - text
thumb_src  - text
title      - text
url        - text
groep      - int
```

I hope someone know whats the problem!

Comment: `OR` in your sql will cause it not work as you expected,and you need to provide more detail for your question

Comment: readed? do your fellow devs a favour and fix that

Comment: @lucumt I added some more info don't know its enough yet. I  tried to remove the OR but still getting 0 results

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query seems correct to me, except the part with the `OR`, so I suppose that the problem is with the data. I will first try to show how you could improve the query nevertheless, and then try to show how to debug your data.

First, let's leave away the `OR` condition since this won't work as expected in a `JOIN ON` clause.

Second, when comparing integer fields to values, you should not put quotes around the values. This will only worry every person who tries to understand the query because the quotes denote *string* values, and it will worry (i.e. slow down) MySQL's parser, because it must convert the string values to numbers.

Third, mixing up normal `WHERE` conditions and `JOIN ON` conditions is worrying and bad style (IMHO). I always recommend to put *only the conditions which actually link the tables* into the `JOIN ON` clause, and other conditions elsewhere.

Following this advice would lead to something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM
  notify INNER JOIN readed ON
    readed.msg_ID = notify.ID
WHERE
  readed.acc_ID = 26 AND
  readed.user_ID = 6 AND
  readed.readed != '1' AND
  notify.groep = 1
```

This should do the same as your original query minus the `OR` part.

Now, since we suspect that there is a problem with the data, we can begin to debug the data. First, leave away the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM
  notify INNER JOIN readed ON
    readed.msg_ID = notify.ID
```

If this returns data, then you at least know that there are rows in the `readed` table matching rows in the `notify` table. If it does not return any data, then there are no rows which fit together, and have found the root of your problem.

Provided that the above returns data, re-add the `WHERE` clause line by line and test after each step. For example, start with

```
SELECT * FROM
  notify INNER JOIN readed ON
    readed.msg_ID = notify.ID
WHERE
  readed.acc_ID = 26 AND
```

and continue with

```
SELECT * FROM
  notify INNER JOIN readed ON
    readed.msg_ID = notify.ID
WHERE
  readed.acc_ID = 26 AND
  readed.user_ID = 6 AND
```

and so on, testing the query each time.

That way, you hopefully will find out where the problem is. I am convinced that the problem is with the data, not with the query.

Comment: I've tried everything you have said above. Everythings seems to work, but i still get 0 results. I self think that the problem is that readed doesnt exsist before the user reads it. But i don't know how to  do that with if not exists skip for asking the DB if the user has read it.

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM readed` give any result? What do you mean by "readed doesn't exist"?

Comment: Readed exists but i never insert data into it before user has it seen his inbox.

Comment: So trying to get it work with something like IF readed NOT EXISTS with values user_ID = 6 AND  acc_ID = 26 THEN user hasnt seen it so i display the message

Comment: SELECT * FROM readed gives no results because it isnt there yet, i dont know how to array all users ID and save it in the DB

Comment: Well, you should have written that before. This had saved a lot of time and effort. Of course, an `INNER JOIN` between two tables yields no results if one of the tables is empty. Look into `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`; this possibly solves your problem.

Comment: Okay i'm going to do it real quick and check if i can fix it. i'm so sorry that i didn't told u earlier :(. Thank you very much for you're time and effort

Comment: So i did a LEFT JOIN it gave the same blank result. after that i added all the data to the readed table and set readed to no. When i did this it worked for me but will not fix it, because then i need to make an Array with all users id and need to add all that data when i send a Notify to all users. Maybe you know a good solution with the Array(). Thanks a lot @binarus

Comment: When you empty the `readed` table again, `SELECT * FROM notify LEFT JOIN readed ON readed.msg_ID = notify.ID` (without the WHERE clause) should give you some records, right?

Comment: Finally getting results this is a great step thank you!

Comment: This one is working now SELECT * FROM notify LEFT JOIN readed ON readed.msg_ID = notify.ID AND readed.user_ID = 6 AND readed.acc_ID = 26 AND readed.readed = 'no' @binarus Thank you so much for helping this is the solution for me!